# Data synchronization during migration from ShareFile to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am ready to migrate content (around 5TB) from ShareFile to SharePoint. I'm analyzing two scenarios; direct transfer with SahreGate tool and second scenario is to download to local server then upload to SharePoint. But concern is about synchronization. Using synchronization lens which scenario is the best and why?